# Get Destination SIM Card phone number in android application

Tags: android

I want to get Phone number of the SIM card in my android application, but I am unable to find a proper solution to this issue.

Comment: can you show what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this code in java file:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

And

Add this line in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```